# PHP header Location opening in Fancybox

Tags: php, fancybox, fancybox-2

Currently I am using Fancybox for links in my page...

e.g.

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe more_info_btn"  href='<?=$someurl?>'>LINK1</a>
```

On my one page I have form , On submit user get redirected to another link . code used is as  follows

```
<?php
.....
.....//all code
// and after that..
$url1 = 'http://example.com/page2.php';

$_SESSION["Register_id"]="suceess";
    header("Location: ".$url1); 
} 
?>
```

I needed help to redirect user with some changes in

```
header("Location: ".$url1);
```

to fancybox opened instead of page2.php in main browser tab ?

Comment: If `header("Location: ".$url1);` is being performed within a fancybox iframe, the redirection should happen inside fancybox, unless I am missing something: is the form opened in fancybox?